# Properties file to create an xml

Tags: java, xml, properties-file

Below is the sample xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<INPUT_REQUEST_MATRIX>
       <REQUEST_RULE>
              <RULE_ID>CONTENT_OF[ID règle]</RULE_ID>
              <REQUEST>CONTENT_OF[Type demande]</REQUEST>
              <PREVIOUS_REQUESTS>CONTENT_OF[A traiter avant]              </PREVIOUS_REQUESTS>
              <DOCUMENT>
                     <DOC_TYPE>CONTENT_OF[Type document]</DOC_TYPE>
                     <REQUIRED>CONTENT_OF[required]</REQUIRED>
                     <INCLUDE_ALL>CONTENT_OF[include-all]</INCLUDE_ALL>
                     <SHARED>CONTENT_OF[shared]</SHARED>
              </DOCUMENT>
       </REQUEST_RULE>
</INPUT_REQUEST_MATRIX>
```

I have to define this xml template in the properties file for example

```
Rootelement=INPUT_REQUEST_MATRIX
element1=REQUEST_RULE    
element2=DOCUMENT
element2.child1=DOC_TYPE
element2.child2=REQUIRED
element2.child3=INCLUDE_ALL
.....
```

The values for the elements will come from an Excel file, so i have read the properties file create an element and map the value from the excel file. 
What is the best way to define the properties file, so its easy to read and create the elements.

Comment: are you using spring boot?

Comment: The best way - do not use properties file, use XML file

Comment: @kan, can you give me more details

Comment: ??? Just create a file `template.xml` and put your xml template into it, then use it as a template.